# Catalyst for Formic acid decomposition

Tags: experimental-chemistry, catalysis

I wanted to decompose formic acid into $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{H2}$ for a school experiment. I was wondering what would be a suitable catalyst to use?

Comment: Please have a look at [decomposition of formic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formic_acid#Decomposition).

Answer (score 3):

In [*A Novel Example of Molecular Hydrogen Generation from Formic Acid at
Visible-Light-Responsive Photocatalyst*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/am900707e), the authors describe the formation of carbon dioxide and hydrogen from formic acid using visible light from a halogen lamp and freshly prepared $\ce{Cu2O}$ (or platinum-covered $\ce{Cu2O}$) as a catalyst.

The preparation of the $\ce{Cu2O}$ is described as follows:

> Ten cubic centimeters of $\mathrm{1.0~mol~dm^{-3}}$
>   $\ce{CuSO4*9H2O}$ aqueous solution was dropped
>   into $\mathrm{100~cm^3}$ of $\mathrm{1.0~mol~dm^{-3}}$ $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ aqueous solution, and
>   subsequently, the mixture solution was dropped into $\mathrm{200~cm^3}$
>   of $\mathrm{1.0~mol~dm^{-3}}$ $\ce{NaOH}$ solution at 80 °C.
>
> The resulting reddish-brown precipitate ($\ce{Cu2O}$) was separated by filtration and washed with deionized water, after which the precipitation was dried at 40 °C in an $\ce{Ar}$ atmosphere.

The conversion of formic acid is described as follows:

> The photocatalytic experiment was conducted in a glass vessel (volume: $\mathrm{20~cm^3}$) containing $\mathrm{10~cm^3}$ of $\mathrm{2.5~mol~dm^{-3}}$ $\ce{HCOOH}$ and a known amount of photocatalyst (10 mg (ca. 70 μmol)) [...] in
>   $\ce{Ar}$ atmosphere with stirring. The pH of the $\ce{HCOOH}$ solution was adjusted to 5.0 by the addition of $\ce{NaOH}$ solution.
>
> A halogen lamp was used as the light source (light intensity: $\mathrm{280~mW~cm^{-2}}$ ) along with a sharp-cut filter (S76-L42, Suruga Seiki Co. Ltd.), using which the samples were irradiated with light of wavelength $\lambda > 420~\mathrm{nm}$. [...]

In summary, it seems possible to perform the experiment at school. UV filters are available from different manufacturers, a [Schott N-WG320](http://www.schott.com/d/advanced_optics/80346694-27b1-44db-833a-114c56fdaa57/1.0/schott-longpass-n-wg320-nov-2016-de.pdf) might work.

Answer (score 1):

The [wikipedia article of formic acid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formic_acid) mention that decomposition of formic acid is carried out in the presence of acid, platinum or ruthenium catalyst.

> Heat and especially acids cause formic acid to decompose to carbon
>   monoxide (CO) and water (dehydration). Treatment of formic acid
>   **with sulfuric acid** is a convenient laboratory source of CO.
>
> **In the presence of platinum**, it decomposes with a release of hydrogen and carbon dioxide.
>
> $$\ce{CH2O2 → H2 + CO2}$$
>
> **Soluble ruthenium catalysts** are also effective(...)

For laboratory purposes, treating it with sulfuric acid is the best way.